# What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?

Tags: support, faq, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

- What are **watched tags** and **ignored tags**? How do they work?
- What are **tag subscriptions**?
- What are **interesting tags**?
- On Stack Overflow, the content of the main page question list appears to be influenced by watched and ignored tags. How does that work?

> For more information, see "[How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)" in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 37):

### Watched Tags

To watch a tag, do one of the following:

- In the popover that appears when you hover over the tag, click on the "Watch tag" button.
- On the main page's right sidebar, in the *Watched Tags* section, click on "Watch a tag" (if you have no watched tags yet), or click on "Edit" next to the section heading (if you have at least one watched tag already).
- Go to the [*Settings* tab of your user profile](/users/preferences/current), then click on the [*Tag watching & ignoring*](/users/tag-notifications/current) link.

Note that [you can use wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) in the latter two.

This has the following effects:

- Questions with these tags become highlighted on the front page.
- Questions with new activity are shown on [stackexchange.com/filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/).
- In the review queues, questions from these tags are shown to you before other questions.
- The search operator `intags:mine` limits search to questions with those tags and answers to such questions. If your "Watched Tags" list is empty, the search operator does nothing.
- On Stack Overflow, this affects how questions are displayed on the home page (*Recent questions*) and the various questions pages.

(Watched tags were formerly known as *interesting tags* and *favorite tags*. They may also be known as *followed tags*.)

### Ignored Tags

To ignore a tag, do one of the following:

- In the popover that appears when you hover over the tag, click on the "Ignore tag" button.
- On the main page's sidebar, in the *Ignored Tags* section, click on *Add an ignored tag* (if you have no ignored tags yet), or click on *Edit* next to the section heading (if you have at least one ignored tag already).
- Go to the [*Settings* tab of your user profile](/users/preferences/current), then click on the [*Tag watching & ignoring*](/users/tag-notifications/current) link.

Note that [you can use wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) in the latter two.

This has the following effects:

- By default, questions with these tags are shown faded/grayed-out; they are still visible, but less prominent. It is possible to hide them completely; for more details, see: [How do I hide posts matching my ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23811)
- On Stack Overflow, this affects how questions are displayed on the home page (*Recent questions*) and the various questions pages.

### Subscribing to a tag

You can no longer choose to receive emails about new activity within a tag. However, you can subscribe via RSS by hovering over the tag, then clicking the orange RSS feed icon in the top-right of the popover that appears.

### See also

- [Expressing Your Tag Preferences](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/)

Comment: > "This will cause you to receive mails about activity in those tags."


I would not subscribe because the last thing I'd want is more email.

Comment: @WillowRex: Well, then don’t do it. Since that’s the only effect of subscribing to a tag, this function was not made for you. It looks as if favouring/following tags is more your kind of thing.

Comment: yes, and I also had no idea what they were for before this.  So thanks!

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!  Except the User/Preferences thing must have gotten changed at some point, it's hidden a little now.  I had to go into my profile, then click "Edit Profile And Settings", then on the left side under Site Preferences there's a Settings link and it's in there.