# How do I hide posts matching my ignored tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

Where and how do I go about hiding the posts that match any of the tags on my ignored list?

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** This answer no longer works due to recent UI changes. Please see [the other answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321052/377214) for the current way.

---

- Go to your profile page.
- Click on the [Edit Profile & Settings tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current).
- Click on the [Preferences sub tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).
- Underneath the Ignored Tags section are two radio buttons, labelled: "Hide questions in your ignored tags" and "Gray out questions in your ignored tags".
- Check the "Hide questions in your ignored tags" and then go about your business.

[image: ignore at your own tag choice]

It will autosave the preference once you check/uncheck. Now, when you're viewing a list of questions, those marked with any of your ignored tags will be removed from view.

They're taken out of your view when they get to your side of things, so keep that in mind when paging through with set amounts per page listings. i.e. if you're thumbing through 50 a page, but you only count 40 on the page at a time, then 10 are being hidden.

Comment: Removal done client-side though.

Comment: Meant client side - do'h

Comment: Good comment about the removal being done client side. There's been a couple of "bugs" reported about that.

Answer (score 12):

Since the other answer was posted, the user interface has changed. Currently you can no longer change this in your user profile preferences.

However, you can change this after you click on "edit" next to the list of ignored tags on the homepage sidebar:

[image: Edit ignored tags]

After that, you choose one of two options: "Hide questions in your ignored tags" and "Gray out questions in your ignored tags".

[image: Hide questions]

Comment: Thank you.  That's hard to find...