# Temporarily disabling 'Ignore' tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Due to the way SO loads questions and then hides 'ignored' tags, I will occasionally see a question (for just a split second) that I actually have some interest in.  It would be really nice to be able to temporarily disable my ignore tags so that I can see all the questions in the queue.

Comment: Do the opposite of this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-do-i-hide-posts-matching-my-ignored-tags

Comment: Hmmm...   I guess what I mean is I only want to quickly and temporarily disable them.  I don't want to have to navigate away from the question page.  But thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Not an exact dupe. The other was a support request (how to). *This* is a feature-request (make it temporary, i.e. easier) for that functionality... as I see it.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant (as in the answer below).  Although when I asked the question I didn't realize that the setting existed at all, so I didn't clarify that I meant that I wanted to be able to toggle directly from the question page.

Comment: Hiding ignored tags sucks when trawling for posts to flag.

Answer (score 39):

I would probably use the "ignored tags" function if I could quickly toggle the setting. It might be nice of the `Hide Ignored Tags` check box was on the questions page.

[image]

Comment: ...with another checkbox beneath it (greyed out if the first one is not checked): `[ ] ...unless it is also interesting`

Comment: @Thingadongdong - do you mean, "unless it is also on one of my interesting tags" - that sounds sensible, but I'd prefer a more sentient system if Jeff could cobble one together.

Comment: Yes this is EXACTLY what I'm hoping for!  :)

Comment: Any chance for implementing this soon?

Comment: This would be so useful when doing spam hunting searches like `url:"http://*spammysite.com*"` -  currently the easiest solution is to have another browser open that you aren't logged in on.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how long it's been like this but I've noticed that the `hide ignored tags` checkbox is there, only it is hidden.  Maybe the team is considering adding it but isn't complete yet.  As far as I can tell, it's working fine enough.

I wrote a greasemonkey script to unhide it.  Now you can toggle hiding these questions directly from the question view pages.  I plan to do more with this in the future including doing something about those also marked interesting.

[Get it from StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2372)