# Don't hide questions when browsing an ignored tag

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I don't think the ignored tags feature should be enabled when searching questions by tag. For example, I have the `iphone` tag hidden in my preferences on Stack Overflow, and so when I go to [search for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) with that tag, the list is empty. This doesn't make much sense, in my opinion; I obviously don't want to ignore iPhone questions if I'm specifically searching for them. **It would be great if ignored tags were not taken into account when searching by tag.** The same applies to interesting tags as well.

To take this a little further, it would also be great if there were a button off to the right on all pages that allowed the user to temporarily toggle the ignored tags feature at will. This way, we'd be able to click a single button/link and see all the questions that have been ignored, and click again to hide them again. Just a suggestion I thought I'd throw out there; I'd be happy with my first proposal, though.

---

Sorry if this has already been posted, I searched and couldn't find anything.

Comment: This came up most recently just yesterday: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags/36737#36737

Comment: This one is specifically for searches. I do feel it is a reasonable request.