# Don't "Hide ignored tags" on search results pages

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily disabling ‘Ignore’ tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36735/temporarily-disabling-ignore-tags)

Hiding ignored tags is useful, for example, if I'm a C# guy but not a Java guy so I like to answer C# questions that I find casually on the front page and ignore the Java questions I can't answer.

However, if I'm looking for a solution to a problem tagged "C#" that's answered in a question that happens to be in some small way related to Java and thus is also tagged "java", then I won't see it.

What do you think?

Comment: I think it's a dupe of many similar questions about the mechanics of interesting and ignored tags.