# Search results change after few seconds

Tags: support, search

When searching on Stack Overflow using SRWare Iron 20.0.1150.1 (which is Google's Chrome browser without Google) I noticed that the search results change after a one or two seconds which is quite annoying if you try to click a question which then disappears right before your eye.

**Steps to reproduce:** Open Stack Overflow in a *Chromium browser* and search for "configuring snmp" or click [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=configuring+snmp)

(After this has been resolved thanks to Martijns answer: You will need to ignore the [java](/questions/tagged/java)-tag and have the 'hide ignored tags'-preference enabled)

**Current behavior:** Search results are being displayed, and after one or two seconds resorted:

Initial result:

[image]

After one or two seconds:

[image]

**Expected behavior:** The search results appear and stay where they are ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably *ignoring* certain tags, and have the 'hide ignored tags' preference enabled.

Ignored tags are handled on the client side, so they are either dimmed or removed from the page when the page has loaded. If you ignore either the [java](/questions/tagged/java) or the [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) the first post will be removed. The third post on that page also uses the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag, it could be removed as well.

If your browser is a little slow, or the network takes a long time to serve some resource used by the page, that can be after a noticeable delay.

In any case, I have [java](/questions/tagged/java) on my ignore list, but have the 'hide ignored tags' preference *disabled*, so the page you linked to looks like this for me:

[image: Dimmed posts on the search results]

The posts are dimmed shortly after the page loaded.

Comment: That's it. Thanks for pointing that out so quickly. Will accept your answer once that is possible.