# Hiding Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide posts matching my ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-do-i-hide-posts-matching-my-ignored-tags)

Is there a way to completely hide questions with ignored tags? Right now they are still visible, just sort of "grayed out." However, they still take up space in the list, and I don't want to see them at all. How do you *really* hide them?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-do-i-hide-posts-matching-my-ignored-tags There's an option in your user profile, under the prefs tab, to "Hide Ignored Tags". Check it, and you're done! ♪

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your user profile and find the `prefs` tab. Select the option marked `Hide Ignored Tags`.