# What does the colored orange bar for the questions mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)
>   [Why is Stack Overflow suddenly orange (#FFEFC6)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange-ffefc6)

This may be a newbie question, but so far I did not understand what the orange colored background for a question indicate. I mean, just click on the "Questions" tab above and when you scroll through the questions, at some point or the other, you will see the complete question, the entire row, colored in orange. What does this really indicate? It does not make sense to me the way it is and I tried to make sense out of it.  I even went through the FAQ but no gains.

Comment: They're questions that have one (or more) of your interesting tags.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, ChrisF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that it has been tagged with one of your "interesting" tags.

Comment: ahhhh... i see..  thank you for the answer.