# Grouping Levels for Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

Every now and then, I update my IGNORE tags lists on stackoverflow so it's easier to browse questions that I might know something about and be able to help with.

If I don't use the IGNORE list, I have to do a ton of scrolling & reading through question pages...

So using the IGNORE list is helpful, but it's still tedius.  For example, if I want to ignore Joomla, since I have nothing to contribute to questions about Joomla, I have to ignore all of the following tags:

```
   - Joomla
   - Joomla1.5
   - Joomla-sef-urls
   - Joomla-template
```

And in addition to those, any new tags folks might create in the future -- Joomla2, Joomla3, etc.

Could it be possible to have a tag structure where, using the example above, "Joomla" would be the parent tag, and all of the others (Jooma1.5, etc.) would be identified by their creator as child-tags of Joomla.  And then, have the ability to ignore Joomla *and all of it's children* in one step?

Besides allowing users to *ignore* parents and all of their children, I can see this helping people to *search* for parents and all of their children as well, all in one swipe.

The parent/child structure could be multi-leveled -- e.g., Gread-grandparent --> Grandparent --> Parent --> Child; just however it made sense for ignoring or searching for entire groups / sub-groups.

Maybe you'd need a new rep step, for folks to have the ability to group tags they didn't create or something.

### EDIT

This is already answered -- but it does lead me to wondering about parents/children with different names.  For example, there's a tag for 'ASP.NET', and there's a tag for 'gridview'.  This kind of parent/child relationship isn't found using wildcards.  I don't think it's a big deal per my original question though -- the wildcard has helped a lot!  But it might not be a replacement for relationships.

Comment: Have you tried ignoring `joomla*`?

Comment: one way to solve this would be renaming some tags, i.e. 'gridview' --> 'asp.net-gridview'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just ignore <kbd>joomla*</kbd>?

More on Wildcards are available on the blog [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) and in the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do)

Comment: Because I'm not smart enough to think of that.  :-)
I'll mark your answer in 10 minutes...

Comment: @dave I added the links to the entries regarding using the feature.