# Can we have preferred tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to be able to select preferred tags so that I could easily choose the questions that really fit me. For example, I don't really care about Python or C, but I love PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS and JavaScript. So why not allow users to pick their favorite tags and bring all the related questions to the home page? I saw that this question has been asked before at least once, but I cannot really figure out how this could not be already done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the Ignored Tags and Interesting Tags fields on the user prefs page do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Interesting Tags and Ignored Tags. Note that you can choose to hide your ignored tags.

Also note that you can click on a tag to see only questions with that tag.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That question has no sense now, so sorry. I'll be choosing you as preferred answer in 3 minutes.