# Background color of Stack Overflow questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-interface, design

Why is the background of some questions light orange and some white?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Light orange means it's tagged with one of your "interesting tags", white means it's not.

See [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do) for some more information.

Answer (score 7):

The light orange questions are in tags that you marked as interesting in your profile page.

This allows you to ignore questions in topics that you aren't interested in.