# What's the new orange highlighting on some questions in the questions list?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-interface, featured-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the “Favorite Tags” feature on stackoverflow work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/how-does-the-favorite-tags-feature-on-stackoverflow-work)

So far I've only seen this on stackoverflow.com. What does it indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means that the questions are in one of your **Favorite Tags**. This isn't new.

Comment: Thanks chris, it's because I never used face tags before. Cheers. Just waiting 10 mins to mark as answer