# Burninate [position], [positioning] and [styles]

Tags: support, burninate-request

These are useless as categorizations. Note that there is a discussion going on [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203777/for-search-effectiveness-shouldnt-so-tags-be-as-generic-as-possible), which is where I discovered these tags, but they are too weak to even be useful when combined with another tag.

Too many instances of these tags for community burnination.  Can we get an SE employee to run a couple of queries perhaps?

[image]

Comment: If anyone wants to help with [tag:positioning], here's [my search query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/positioning+-wordpress+-div+-css+-html+-css3+-jquery+-javascript) for finding all the non-CSS related ones. I've been slowly working through it until it hits zero, then was just going to merge it into [tag:css-position].

Comment: **+1** Best burnination image I've seen yet. Also, burninate.

Comment: @animuson: [Uh oh.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/position+-wordpress+-div+-css+-html+-css3+-jquery+-javascript)

Comment: @Robert Don't remind me of that tag. I don't want to think about that monstrosity just yet. ;P I've been holding out for that conditional merge feature request.