# Save custom URL in sidebar

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

I often browse Stack Overflow using custom search URLs, like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash+or+awk
```

It would be nice if we could save such custom URLs in the sidebar of the Android app for quick access.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saved searches in Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163341/saved-searches-in-stack-overflow)

Comment: @SQB Not sure it is an *exact* duplicate, because the other question is not specifically about the android app.

Comment: True, although the general idea of saving search queries _is_. That is the main feature, I think.