# How can I create my own tag collection

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

such that I can filter new open queestions based on my personal set of tags?

When I hover a tag I can subscribe to it for email notifications, but that is not what I want. I just want to filter unanswered questions by my tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the homepage to the right you can add "Favorite Tags". This helps customize your homepage and the questions you see. I believe tags your favorite tags get highlighted with a yellow/goldish background whereas normal ones that creep through simply have a white background. You can also click the tags to get a list of questions that have that specific tag (i.e. if you clicked the tag [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) it'd show you all questions that were tagged under [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

See this question: [How does the "Favorite Tags" feature on stackoverflow work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/how-does-the-favorite-tags-feature-on-stackoverflow-work)