# Adding feature in ignored/interesting tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I recently saw that often the ignored and interesting tags coexist. On some sites where tags are also used, sometimes there is an option for combining the tags.

What I mean, for example I interested in JavaScript, ASP, but not in JSP. So if there is a check-box for combine ( or something more accurate for the occasion ). Then I can check it and all ASP questions will be highlighted, and all of the questions that contain JavaScript without JSP tag. Or highlight in a different color... Can it be done?

I think it will add a nice touch to that system.

Edit - I meant this.

[image: ignored tag highlighted]

Comment: There are no "Interesting Tags" anymore, they've been renamed to "Favorite Tags". In fact, that screenshot seems... odd. The CSS is different from Stack Overflow. I think you're running into issues on account of possibly running some special script? We don't have all of those checkboxes. If you want proper elements, please use the "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags" located beneath all of that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in your Favorite tags, and [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) in your Ignored tags, you'll get exactly this functionality. You just need to add them separately, no other steps needed.

Specifically, anything with either of the first two tags will be highlighted. Anything that has the latter tag will be dimmed (or hidden, if you set your preferences thus), and this overrides any favorite tags. As such, it will also cover that your JavaScript highlights will only be the ones that do not have JSP tagged on them.

Comment: [The community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do) touches on the basics of tag preferences, but it apparently skimps on explaining the effects of having multiple tags on each. Which is not necessarily all that intuitive, depending on where you're familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quetiion, it was my fault. Someone has added a little script via Greacemonkey.