# How can I hide questions that don't interest me based on tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Posts on Stack Overflow that I don't like to see (based on the tags I have set as "ignored") are hidden, but on Server Fault, they're just displayed as partially transparent. How can I hide them completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: hide ignored tag preference checkbox]

(in the prefs tab of your profile)

Comment: I don't remember I did same thing on SO. But thanks a lot