# Filter for Objective C only

Tags: support, profile-page, search, tag-watching

Is there a way I can do a search, without typing "Objective C" each time, and make it my default area?  I don't care about C, C++, Android, PHP, etc. (at this point in my life).

Comment: Yes, you can do it by using the objective-c `tag`.

Comment: However, be aware that only a fraction of the questions that actually involve Objective-C are tagged as such. You may need to look to [cocoa] for Mac development and [iphone] or [ios] to catch the vast majority of iOS questions.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, bookmark the URL, here is one that should do what you want:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c?sort=newest

Answer (score 5):

Type `[objc]` into the search box. [objc](/questions/tagged/objc) is a synonym for [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c), and the bare tag search will take you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c, sort of the "home page" for questions tagged [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c).

If you have a facility allowing some kind of custom search shortcut to be defined (my browser, OmniWeb, has this built-in), you can make e.g., `so $arg` perform a Stack Overflow search. Then `so [objc]` will take you to that page.

You can also make [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) one of your ["favorites"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do), giving you one-click access in the sidebar from almost any page.