# How many downvotes to push an active question off the "active" list?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes, active

I just noticed that the question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117107/do-you-also-have-difficulty-reaching-your-rep-quota-during-christmas doesn't appear in the "active" list.  If this list were based purely on last modified time, it would be there; so I am assuming that a question will no longer appear in the active questions list at a certain number of downvotes.

Just out of curiosity, is the exact number of downvotes that it takes to kick a question off the active list publicly available or are the details of this functionality purposefully undisclosed?

(or is there another reason that invalidates my initial assumption of it being based on downvotes?)

Comment: Currently, I see a [-6 question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117082/filter-for-objective-c-only) on the list, and the question above has -8, sooo...carry the 1.... is it in the -7/-8 range?

Comment: 'to kick a question off the active list' -sounds vicarious to me :) -just kidding in this case, tho.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769) on a request to make metas more lenient in this regard, questions will be pushed off the front page of normal sites once they reach a score of -4, and only once they reach a score of -8 on meta sites.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for digging that up!

Comment: Does a bounty override this push?

Answer (score 2):

There exist 2 active lists:

1. https://*.stackexchange.com/?tab=active
2. https://*.stackexchange.com//questions?tab=Active

https://*.stackexchange.com/?tab=active has a limit on the number downvotes, as [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) mentions in their [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/178179). https://*.stackexchange.com//questions?tab=Active has no limit.