# Live question update shows items that wouldn't normally show on the front page

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, homepage

The recently deployed realtime updates display some questions that they shouldn't, based on what would be expected to appear on the front page's active question list:

[image: example of questions that should likely not be displayed]

In the first instance, a question with [too many negative votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/150235) to be shown on the active list is displayed anyway.

In the second case, there's no registered activity on the question, but the question was displayed as if something had happened (I submitted an edit without changing anything, so it was completely a noop).

In a third case, I saw Kevin's edit (which you can't see in the revision history because he reverted it, for anyone confused by this) of [this deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118478/150235) appear.

It doesn't make much difference whether or not they're displayed, but since they wouldn't appear if you were to refresh the page, it seems a little inconsistent.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic: this is AngryDeletionFest.SE now, not MSO.

Comment: I figured a little mild-manner sanity wouldn't hurt...although I couldn't come up with a ridiculous title, so I suppose I've failed Meta.

Comment: Is this still going on?  I haven't seen one of these popup on the front page in a while (perhaps @GeoffDalgas fixed it already?)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Hmm, I'm not sure. I actually kind of liked when I could see the deleted/low-vote questions, so in some sense I was hoping it'd be marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. I'm less interested in the no-op edit, but that's partially another issue (and a pretty contrived example on my part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low voted posts will no longer show up via realtime updates.