# Does downvoting a question help "hide" it?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many downvotes to push an active question off the “active” list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117119/how-many-downvotes-to-push-an-active-question-off-the-active-list)

The question [Find and replace first space in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604273/find-and-replace-first-space-in-a-string), while very much a question where the OP apparently hasn't tried Googling first, doesn't seem to fit any of the close reasons, so I downvoted it instead.

Does downvoting a question help "hide" it in any way? I checked the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down), and grepped [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), and neither mention downvoting "hiding" a question. I also couldn't find anything [searching for "[faq] voting"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[faq]+voting) either.

Comment: That depends on what you mean with 'hiding'. If you mean 'sliding off the frontpage faster' then, yes. If you mean 'will be lost and forgotten', then no.

Comment: If by "hide" you mean "do not display on the main page at all," [then yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/131713). Score of -4 suppresses posts on "main sites"; -8 does the same on metas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on whether you have access to the 10k tools...:

[image: No freehand circles.]

No freehand circles I'm afraid, but there you see a review of questions with high down votes over varying period. This is available to *all* 10k+ users, so if a question has received unfair treatment from the community, we are able to edit/vote to fix it.

As I understand it, on the home page of main sites, -4 is the lowest a question may score before it disappears from view. *However*, it still appears in the question list. Any quality flags it triggers will appear in review; also, if it attracts close votes it will appear in review, where it must be reviewed by 2 (?) users before it is deemed "reviewed".

In short, there are many ways in which downvoted content is exposed and can be reviewed. If you have the 10k tools, or access to review, you have an advantage.