# How does downvoting impact a post view count?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, views

If a question accumulates downvotes, does the post receive any more or less attention?

I am aware of the Twitter Bot which increases exposure for high-score posts. I am wondering if there is a corollary feature which actively changes a post's exposure due to down-voting. For example, does a low-scoring post get systematically or automatically dragged to the bottom of a page or excluded from certain meta searches?

This question arises from curiously weak responses to what the Internet considers to be "hot" topics, per Google and Yahoo.

Comment: We don't have historical viewcounts for a question (answers don't have a viewcount) so it is not possible to answer this based on the public data. You need SE staff to run this query on their internal SEDE instance.

Answer (score 3):

If a question has a score of -4 or lower (-8 on Meta sites), it's [hidden from the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/295232), so it's less likely to attract views. (It's still visible in other question lists and the search pages.)

Other than that, there might be psychological effects at work (either "Oh, a downvoted question, I *must* check out what's wrong with it" or "A downvoted question? That can't be worth my time") but it's going to be nearly impossible to measure this; views aren't tracked real time, so it's hard to analyse how many views a question gets while it's downvoted.

Comment: This is a great answer. How does SE prevent cliques from controlling users' by pushing their posts down to the very-easy-to-reach -4? Can you please include what protections if any exist? It seems prone to abuse itself. For example, some grace period allowing a post to reach enough people to form a meaningful average?

Comment: The protection is that (we hope that) normal users do see the questions and notice something strange is going on with the voting and flag for moderator attention.

Comment: Also, see this experiment on Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390178/4751173