# Favourite / Ignored tags conflict

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Let's say I have [java](/questions/tagged/java) as a favourite tag and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) as an ignored tag.

If somebody tags a question with both  [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), it is ignored and does not appear in my list of newest questions.

I would personally like to see this question as it might be interesting / relevant to me.

**Would it not make sense that the favourite tag had a higher priority than the ignored tag when there is a conflict?**

Comment: I ran into this some time ago, also spend some time thinking about it. If you have an ignored tag, think about why it is ignored...just for a moment...and now ask yourself: Would like to see this tag even if it has a tag that interests you? While you might say "yes", is that the same for all ignored tags? ...Ahhrm...long story short, if you have the question `[java] [swing]` and `[java]` is a favorite tag, but you ignored `[swing]` because you can't stand that piece of crap (hypothetically speaking of course), would you like to see that question?

Comment: @UristMcBobby I get your point (although completely hypothetical!). There could maybe be a sort of code. Say ignoring `[swing]` would leave the questions where it appears together with a favourite tag, while ignoring `[swing-NO-PLIZ]` would be similar to the current behaviour...

Comment: @UristMcBobby And imagine somebody tagging `[swing]` as well as your `[favourite-java-ui]`, you won't even be able to try to educate the unworldly users!

Comment: I think the current behaviour is what one would expect. Compare google advanced search, option "none of these words:". Would you still want to see sites that have the words you're looking for _and_ the excluded words? Intuition says no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Favorite Tags**: questions with these tags become highlighted. Formerly known as "interesting tags."

**Ignored Tags**: questions with these tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent.  Checking the "Hide Ignored Tags" box causes them to be hidden completely (this is done by a client-side script however, so you may notice odd "gaps")...

On Stack Overflow, these preferences affect how questions are displayed on the home ("Recent questions") page and the various Questions pages.

Source : [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/178505)

> Would it not make sense that the favourite tag had a higher priority
> than the ignored tag when there is a conflict?

If question is tagged with **Favorite Tag** and **Ignored Tag** and Favorite Tag might have higher priority but question can be about ignore tag oriented. How can you identify question favourite tag oriented? Hence You have to arrange properly **Favorite Tags** and **Ignored Tags** lists.

#### See also: [Expressing Your Tag Preferences](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/)

Comment: That's not what I see on the newest questions page - questions with ignored tags do not appear at all.

Comment: @assylias - do you have the "hide ignored tags" option checked. It's on your profile page

Comment: @ChrisF Yup - didn't know that option existed.

Comment: @ChrisF Actually that does answer my question: I now see the conflicts: greyed out + yellow. Good stuff :-)

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. On Cross-Validated.SE, for example, ignored tags simply override watched tags altogether. It's not at all clear from your answer how to change that.