# More advanced favourited / ignored tag system

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

In short, I would like to not see any [php](/questions/tagged/php) questions, except those also tagged with [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm).

I currently ignore and hide the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag, and I've favourited the [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag.

But this is insufficient for my requirements, as [php](/questions/tagged/php) [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) questions are also hidden.

Can we make the favourited / ignored tag system a bit more advanced?

Say, for example, allow me to specify priority (so a favourite will outweigh a lower priority ignore). On an implementation level, just having a few buckets would be sufficient - favourite priority 1, ignore priority 2, favourite priority 3, ignore priority 4, favourite priority 5, ignore priority 6 (or maybe just 4 buckets) (each bucket can have any number of tags).

Note: Feel free to read "[php](/questions/tagged/php)" as (insert tag you don't care for here) and "[algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm)" as (insert tag that's awesomeness outweighs your lack of care for aforementioned tag).

[Related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140383/favourite-ignored-tags-conflict), although that just wants to switch how it works / discuss it, which is not really the same as this.