# Add "Reload with ignored tags" link

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

Currently, if you have ignored tags, you get the following message at the bottom of most question list pages (like [the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/)):

> Hiding questions because of your [Ignored Tags preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1711796) for tags:
>
> [tag1](/questions/tagged/tag1) [tag2](/questions/tagged/tag2) [tag3](/questions/tagged/tag3) ...

Can we perhaps get something like the following added to this message:

> [Reload the page ignoring these preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/?withIgnoredTags)

If you note the link, you'll see I added `?withIgnoredTags` (feel free to suggest / implement something better), which would follow a similar format to already existing functionality, e.g. the page number - `?page=1`.

Needless to say, clicking here would reload the page and display questions even if they contain of your ignored tags, but displaying the ignored tags is **temporary** (based solely on whether the flag appears in the URL) - it would *not* change your ignored tags preferences - if you go to another page, you'll still be ignoring the same tags.

**Justification**

Whether enough people would find this useful is up to you, but I certainly would - sometimes I want to look only at questions with tags I'm not ignoring, and other times I want to look at all questions - favouriting won't really work as I typically *want* to see tags I don't explicitly want to avoid.

This would also help with the following scenario (to which [I suggested a multi-layer favourite / ignore tags system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199193/more-advanced-favourited-ignored-tag-system) some time ago, which would become largely obsolete, at least for me) - I don't, for example, want to see [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) questions in general, but when I look at [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) questions, I do want to see them, as these questions often allow for a non-language-specific answer.

Presumably the above bar is only displayed when you *have* ignored tags, thus this change won't bug you if don't. It also shouldn't take up too much space if displayed - we might even be able to put it on the same line as "Hiding questions ..." and/or shorten it to, for example:

> Reload ignoring preferences

Or:

> Reload with ignored tags

**Compromise - hidden feature**

I'd also be perfectly happy if this was more of a hidden feature - adding `?withIgnoredTags` to the URL would work to do the above, but there is no link on the page. Although it would probably make sense to have a link / mention of it *somewhere*.