# How do I change "My Tags" to ones more relevant to me?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

I have been a member on StackOverflow for years, but have never been extremely active. I'm trying to get a little more active, but when I go to the "Unaswered" section on StackOverflow, I get questions tagged with tags I setup years ago. These questions are no longer extremely relevant to me, so I'd like to setup new tags to help filter the Unaswered questions. I saw how to change the tags to ignored, but that doesn't remove them from the view, it just grays them out.

Comment: go to the "prefs" option and set up your new favorite tags, questions in the front page/unanswered are mostly from your favorite tags. You can also set an option on that page to totally remove hidden tags

Answer (score 0):

Access your Edit Profile & Settings section > under Site Settings, click Preferences and scroll down until you find Favorite Tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are more ways now (four years after question was asked), see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)