# Where are questions using my favorite tags highlighted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-watching

Reading the most up-voted answer for [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) I notice the following sentence:

> On Stack Overflow, these preferences affect how questions are displayed on the home ("Recent questions") page and the various questions pages.

Which are those various question pages where the questions using my favorite tags are highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have favorite tags, they will highlight entries in the list of questions.. regardless of where you're at. You may have to pay close attention to see it at first, because each site has its own theme and way of highlighting these entries.