# Save favorites tags to get questions notifications

Tags: discussion, questions, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

I think that it would be interesting if on Stack Overflow there was an option to save some tags as favorites. When someone posts a question related to this tag you should get a notification. It could be interesting if you are working in some technology that is not very popular.

What do you think?

Comment: These posts may help you [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/166025) and [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/166025)

Comment: Erm... Are you missing the Favourite Tags option on the right hand bar when browsing SO? Or am I missing a key ingredient here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's already done. If you subscribe to a topic, you can receive daily an email with all the new posts related to your favorite tag. Enter in [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) and take a look.