# Will a tagged question which is both favorite and ignored still show up?

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

On stackoverflow I have Emacs as a favorite tag, and many tags involved with HTML ignored. However, there could be the scenerio of an HTML user wanting advice about Emacs, I would still like to see those questions. Will I still see the questions tagged both Emacs and HTML?

Comment: possible dup. of [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/187824)

Comment: Agreed. It is just really difficult to find.

Comment: Tip: If you have any questions related to basic functions, first try to search from [this main FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/187824)

Comment: Should this be closed then?

Comment: This will be closed by community. Don't worry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will still see those questions, but they'll be displayed in a dimmed fashion.

I follow the `python` tag, for example, but ignore `C++`, so I see this:

[image: dimmed question display]

You *can* hide questions with ignored tags altogether though, but you have to do so explicitly. On your `prefs` screen (from your profile) you can check the `hide ignored tags` option:

[image: hide ignored tags option]

Comment: I think that if you choose to hide ignored tags though, you won't see those questions at all.

Comment: Is that the default? Where do I change it?

Comment: @Dualinity: Updated, it's not the default.