# How to filter uninteresting questions

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

I get a lot from Stack Overflow, I want to contribute to others' questions too, but numerous .net, html questions come to the front page, while what I am good at is c and linux. How to filter those questions and just show questions related to my favorite tags?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I know that, but it's too intricate due to massive number of tags while what I want to see is a few tags.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do

Comment: @Oded It seems like we need to have a lot of ignored tags to filter out the questions we have no interests in. Is it possible to select just the few that are of interest?

Comment: @Antony You want the same thing as me.

Comment: @Antony - That's what the favorite tags are for. We don't currently have a mechanism for "only show me questions with these tags: *` on the homepage.

Comment: @Oded So we don't have something like recommended questions, or favorite tag questions alike stuff? I really think these functions are very important.

Comment: @dspjm - You can always subscribe to the RSS feed of any specific tag. Just hover over the tag and at the top right of the card there are subscribe and rss links.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather nice guide to answering questions on SO here: http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/14/the-smart-guide-to-stack-overflow-zero-to-hero/ Pay special attention to the section titled "Specialize, Follow Tags & Automate".

I think you'll find it useful to skip the front page entirely, and use either [Unanswered - My Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags) (which will use either your favorite tags or the top tags you've been active in) or a custom tag filter such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+linux*?sort=unanswered).