# Are questions on the front page also filtered based on our recent activity?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

When answering questions on Stack Overflow, even if they don't have one of your favorite tags, it seems that you are subsequently presented with more questions on similar topics. Say I'm answering a Python question, even when the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag is not part of my favorites, then it seems that the questions shown to me on the front page include more Python questions.

Is that the case? Are questions somehow filtered based on our most recent participation within a tag as well as our favorite tags?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: Are you asking if the questions shown to you are somehow filtered based on your participation in a tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't think that's what the OP is getting at. It's more the "I have just answered a question on Python, and now I get all these Python questions" type of deal. Even if that's not a favorite tag.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha NO! That's not what I am asking! :/

Comment: @Bart yeah! that's what I need to ask!

Comment: Then put it on hold for unclear, because I 100% don't get what he's asking.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Check if my edit is what you actually wanted to ask. If not, roll it back, or tell me to do so.

Comment: @Bart absolutely! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a component of your most active tags in the homepage, even without using favorite/ignored tags.

I don't know how significant it is, and in any case, it's best that you fine-tune that list using favorite and ignored tags.

Answer (score 2):

The questions on your homepage that are labelled "interesting" are indeed related to your participation. There is a feature on Stack Overflow that [calculates the questions that will most likely be interesting to you in the future](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/). You can see how your participation in various tags affects the questions being displayed on the homepage by looking at your **Tag Future report**:

> https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

There you can see a breakdown of the tags that Stack Overflow thinks that you will be most likely to be interested in. The questions on the homepage are filtered by both the favorite/ignored tags and the results in the tag future report.