# Can we please get a /users/me URL?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

When describing certain activities to new users, it often becomes necessary to direct them to their user profile. I got to thinking that it would be nice if we had a `/users/me` URL that would automatically redirect to their actual profile URL. Then we could provide a link that any user could click and they would be directed to their profile page. As an added bonus, the query string could be included in the redirect, allowing anyone to create a link to a certain *tab* in a user's profile.

Naturally if the user is not logged in, the URL would redirect to the login page or something similar.

Comment: Heh, I was thinking this the other day. On a related note, I recently found out that [`/election/latest`](http://stackoverflow.com/election/latest) exists, although it doesn't respect query parameters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This URL goes to your current profile:

```
/users/current
```

It also accepts query strings:

```
/users/current?tab=reputation
```

Comment: It's like magic! How do the SE gods do it?!?

Comment: Also awaiting bug reports with URL encoding and the rediredt... It won't be long!

Comment: How did you find this? :)

Comment: @NathanOsman The [tag future report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187633/209357) uses `current` to refer to the user who has logged in: [`users/tag-future/current`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current)