# How do I get a list of sites where I'm a member of?

Tags: support, user-accounts, network-profile

How do I get a list of sites where I'm a member of?

I've been gone a long while and I want to start using Stack Exchange again.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/941999/inemesit-affia?tab=accounts

Comment: I'm surprised I couldn't find a clear duplicate for this rather basic question. It seems this feature is well-known but not really documented.

Comment: Don't. You don't want to, at least not now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent support for /current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298748/inconsistent-support-for-current) - quite the different question, but certainly the answer (first link, "Accounts" tab, is easy to figure out).

Comment: I retracted a previous duplicate vote, so I can't submit a new suggestion, but the duplicate is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85561/282094 @Glorfindel

Comment: It's not a duplicate . Different questions , same answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts

Comment: This is the better answer for linking to the one all users can use

Comment: *flags as link-only answer*

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to get there:

- The link mentioned by Cerbrus works and is the easiest if you're on this very page, or you bookmark it: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts. It works because Stack Exchange [automatically replaces `current` in the URL with your network account ID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187935/295232) (which is different from your user ID on one of the sites). In your case it will redirect to https://stackexchange.com/users/941999/inemesit-affia?tab=accounts.
- From your own profile on the site, which you can access by clicking the user card in the top bar, you can either click on the Profile tab on the top left (your own profile page opens on the Activity tab by default), and then the link 'View network profile' in the bottom right.

  [image]

  You can also click on the 'Network profile' link in the top right, but you will end up on a different tab ('top') and will have to click the 'accounts' tab first.

  [image]
- Another way is just to navigate to https://stackexchange.com (or click the Stack Exchange logo in the top bar and then the button 'Visit Stack Exchange'), click on your avatar in the top bar (no reputation and badges are shown there) and then choose the 'accounts' tab as indicated in the previous picture.

Answer (score 1):

These are listed on your user profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/941999/inemesit-affia?tab=accounts down along the left hand side:

[image]