# How to filter based on tags in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tag-search

I am quite new to Stack Overflow and I want to help others by answering their questions. Of course, I want to search for questions that I could answer and 'tag' seems to be a good way. However, I cannot find how to filter questions based on multiple tags. The only thing I find is only to select one tag. As I learn rather widely but not deeply, I need to search multiple times in order to find a questions that i could contribute.

Is there a way to have a set of tags such that questions have either one of these tag will appear?

For example, for me, I would want to look into questions with tags (C/C++/Python/Linux/Objective-C/Android/iOS ... )

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do might be of interest too

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can do that** by typing in search field something like that : "`[tag] [tag2] [tag3]`"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have a set of tags such that questions have either
>   one of these tag will appear?

Yes, try search like these [[c] or [c++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c++). With this search either of your requested tagged question will be shown..