# Advanced topic search

Tags: feature-request, sorting, languages

I would like to help this community by giving quality answers to as many questions as I can during the downtime at work or in the evenings at home, but I am only experienced in programming in certain languages.

Would it be an idea to implement a feature that allows you to only show questions asked in a certain subset of the languages? e.g. show all the questions asked about general, java, php and html?

**Edit**

I know there is a way to select a tag from the side, but that will only show one language. What I'm trying to get at here is the ability to select languages, save those in your profile settings and have a tab on the "questions" page that will show you all relevant topics. So next to the "Hot Topics" and "Newest", you would be able to select "MyTags" or "My Languages" or whatever you want to call it.

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options. First, you can add the tags you're interested in to your Favorites list in the sidebar on the Questions page of the main site.  This will highlight questions with those tags, and favor them when populating the Stack Overflow home page.  Second, you can set up a [custom filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) on the Stack Exchange site that will show only questions in the tags you specify.

Comment: Third: click on a tag (from your Favorites, for example) to view only questions with that tag.

Comment: @JDB Sure, but that only shows you 1 tag - I was trying to use multiple and by doing so create a list at once. I might be overthinking it though :)

Comment: @Voidpaw You could do a search for multiple tags, but then you have to either save a link somewhere or type it in every time you visit the site.  For example, you could bookmark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+php+html to view questions with all three of those tags.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Hence why I asked for a way to save that in your preferences, so that you have a tab "MyTags" or something next to the "newest" and "hot topics" etc. (Only works when logged in though of course.)

Comment: @Voidpaw - I get what you are asking, but only after reading your comments. You may want to update your feature request - it's not very clear at the moment.

Comment: @JDB Thanks for the advice, I have added it to the topic now.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably going to fall into the "nice to have" category, but I don't think it's very practical.

As Bill said in [his post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203557/191410), there are already several ways to accomplish your goal. Creating a feature like this would cost developer time (aka money) and would add additional complexity to the site, requiring the maintenance of support documents and "tickets" and probably generating bug reports and the like. Overall, it just doesn't add *that* much value to the user experience, in my opinion.

If there are particular tags which you have no interest in which frequently clutter your view of the main page, I believe you can add them to your "ignored" tags and choose to hide them (see [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)).

Personally, I like to work a single tag at a time. If I get into [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) mode, then switching tracks, to [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) or [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for example, tends to just slow me down.