# How to search for questions without two specific tags

Tags: support, tags

Imagine there is tag1 and tag2

I would like to get all the results of the search for posts that do not contain any of those two tags.

What I have tried:

/tagged/-tag1 -tag2

It didn't work.

Comment: If you don't have any other search criteria you could just use ignored tags (although that's more of a permanent-ish thing than a search)

Comment: @Caj, thanks for the answer,but how to use ignored tags ?

Answer (score 1):

For excluding tags use,

```
"" -[tag-name]
```

If don't have search string, then leave the quotes empty.

[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22%22%20-%5bdiscussion%5d)

Comment: I don't have any search string, just 2 tags which I want to exclude

Comment: Did you tried the edited string pattern?

Comment: yes , it gives me Questions and answers in separate post results, which is weird. How can I limit to only questions ?

Comment: use [`is:question`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%22+-%5Bdiscussion%5D+is%3Aquestion) after tagnames

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other search criteria you could use ignored tags, although that is more of a permenant setting than a quick search.

It's all explained in [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/307988) Simply go to your [preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences), set some ignored tags and select "Hide questions in your ignored tags":

> [image: Hide questions in your ignored tags]