# Pirate's eye (Feature request to disable watched/ignored-tags with a single click)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, design, filtering

**The Pirate's eye**[image: 1] [image: 2]

The current design of all stack-exchange sites allow the users to *Watch* and *Ignore* tags. The purpose of this feature has been described in the following post:

[What do “watched tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/826559)

> Watching tags have the following effects:
>
> 1. Questions with these tags become highlighted on the front page.
> 2. Questions with new activity are shown on stackexchange.com/filters.
> 3. In the review queues, questions from these tags are shown to you before other questions.
> 4. On Stack Overflow (and very active sites), this affects how questions are displayed on the home page (Recent questions) and the various questions pages.

Stack Exchange permits the user to watch multiple tags at once (Upper limit is not known, probably all the tags available on the site). An example of which can be seen below

[image: An example of watched tags menu]

**Feature Requests:**

1. Convert the symbol [image: Eye symbol] to interactive such that upon mouseclick the symbol can alter between [image: Eye] and [image] the purpose of which will be to ignore the current list of watched tags and not use any filtering algorithms to view questions on the main page.
2. Change the ignored tag icon [image] to interactive as well, so that the filter when disabled is a part of `class="answer highlighted-post deleted-answer"` which visually looks like

[image]

**Pros:**

1. Ease of altering between filtered preview and unfiltered preview of a specific page (Active, Interesting, Bountied, etc.).
2. Gives scope for answering questions or reading about existing answers which can also contribute to overall knowledge of the user.

Comment: _"unfiltered preview"_ Isn't that exactly what you get in [/questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active) (specifically, the "Active" tab)?

Comment: @41686d6564 Oh that's extremely unfiltered. The home page shows "interesting" questions with the tags...I cannot possible create such a thing unless I open an incognito tab, question updated to fit what I want to imply

Comment: @Queenie Are you sure you are on the "Active", not the "Newest" tab? I just checked on a couple of sites where I don't have any watched tags and the same list of questions on the home page are shown as the first questions on `/questions?tab=Active`. The only difference is that on the `/questions` page, it displayed part of the body along with the title.

Comment: yes, i am sure, i reconfirmed on math.stackexchange, you are probably looking on a less active or extremely active site (speculation)

Comment: @Queenie Yeah, looks like you're right.

Comment: I'm not sure about the usefulness of this feature. AFAICT, the watched tags widget doesn't filter out any question, just highlights questions with watched tags (correct me if I'm wrong). However the ignored tags widget does filter out questions (if you selected the option), so this feature would make sense there (to ignore the ignored tags).